# Mongo DB Collection Versioning

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Are there any best practices or ways we can use to version a collection or objects in a collection in Mongo DB?

The requirement of versioning a collection is because, the objects in the collection maybe added with new attributes going forward but the already added objects (i.e. old objects) will not be having these attributes and the values for these new attributes. So on retrieval, we need to make sure, the code is not broken in de-serializing the different versions of the same object in the collection.

I can think of adding a version attribute to the objects explicitly, but are there any better built in alternatives in Mongo DB for handling this versioning of objects and/or collections.

Thanks,
Bathiya

Comment: How many versions are possible? Two or more?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best approach would be to update all objects in a batch process when you start using the new software on the server, since otherwise you’ll never know when an object will be updated and you’ll need to keep the old versions of those forever around.

Another thing what I’m doing so far, and it worked (so far), to have the policy to only allow adding new properties to the object. This way in worst case the DB won’t have all the data, but that is fine with all the json-serializers I know. But this means you aren’t allowed to delete or rename properties as well as modifying their type (from scalar value to object, array; from object to scalar, array; …).

Since usually I want to store additional information instead of less, this seems like a good solution without any real limitation for me.

If you need to change the type because scalar value isn’t enough, you can still create some code around which would transform it for every object which has the old value into the new one. And if a bulk update from your side is able to perform the changes I’d still do it but sometimes it needs user input.

For instance if you used to save passwords only as md5-hash it was a scalar value. But someone told you, they should be stored as sha512 with a salt together, now you need an object field for the password, you could call it password_sha512 where you store the salt and the hashed password.